# Removing title bar of android application

Tags: java, android

I'm making a small android application, and I want to remove the android title bar.

I've tried using the

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

But it still makes the title bar show for 0,1 second when the application starts. I would love to make it not even show it when the app is loading.

I've searched a bit around, and somebody mentions that you can change the style of the app, but I have no idea how to do that. I've only just started making apps, so I don't have a lot of experience.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

try this:

in your application tag in manifest add `android:theme`,like follow:

`<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" ...>`

Comment: Worked perfectly. I had to put it in the `<activity>` though, not in application.

Comment: Another question. The android is made for 4.0, which means that it has a special design (as seen in the first picture on [this picture](http://imgur.com/a/h2hB6)), but I would love to disable the title-bar and keep the design. When I use the Theme.noTitleBar, it goes back to the design shown in the second picture. Is there any way to get the first theme with no title bar?

Also, sorry about the danish gibberish. :-)

Answer (score 6):

To do that I declared a style inheriting everything from my general style. This style disabled the default Android titleBar.

```
<style name="generalnotitle" parent="general">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Create a new style and add this style in your different views or add this code in the default style to disabled the titleBar for all windows!

Answer (score 2):

In your AndroidManifest `<activity>` tag, add:

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but I think putting your code before `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` may help...

also I recommend :

```
this.getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

(working for me)